# Regex to parse json formatted string

Tags: regex, grafana, logstash-grok

I have a JSON formatted string which I am trying to parse using a regex. I would like to parse each key value pair for later use in grafana (the regex itself is used in logstash).

The test string looks like this:

```
{
  "version":"1.1",
  "nameId":"test",
  "productId":"B2",
  "total customers":99,
  "full_description":"asdf"
}
```

I am using the following regex expression, but it seems that if the value is a number (without " "), it groups the comma inthe the value. For example, the group value for the key "total customers" is "99," and not just "99".

```
(?i)["'](?<key>[^"]*)["'](?:\:)["'\{\[]?([\r\n]?\t+\")?(?<value>\w(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9_=]\.?)+\w+@(?:(?:\w[a-z\d\-]+\w)\.)+[a-z]{2,10}|true|false|[\w+-.$\s=-]*)(",[\r\n])?(?2)?(?J)(?<value>(?&value))?
```

What do I have to add to the regex expression in order to parse JSON-values which are numbers?

Comment: What have you tried? You can use `\:"?(\d+)"?,` and depend on the language you can just extract regex using regex group matched

Comment: @SinhNguyen I forgot to show the regex I am using. Where do I have to put \:"?(\d+)"?, in order for the regex to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part in the pattern `[\w+-.$\s=-]` has a range `+-.` instead of matching either a `+` `-` or `.`

The range matches ASCII chars decimals number 43-46 where number 44 matches the unwanted `,`

As the character class already matches `-` at the end, so you can omit the middle `-`.

The pattern contains some superfluous escapes and capture groups and seems a bit complicated. The updated pattern with just 2 capture groups could look like;

```
(?i)["'](?<key>[^"]*)["']:["'{\[]?(?:[\r\n]?\t+")?(?<value>\w(?:\s[a-zA-Z\d_=]\.?)+\w+@(?:\w[a-z\d-]+\w\.)+[a-z]{2,10}|true|false|[\w+.$\s=-]*)(?:",[\r\n])?(?2)?(?J)(?<value>(?&value))?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qZvB3d/1)